# Where to implement logout functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I am naive in iOS. I'm designing an app with logout functionality where the logout button is embedded in `UITableViewCell` and it is represented as popover. On implementing the logout functionality in the `UITableViewCell` it is throwing me an error saying no visible user interface. If anyone can help me in coding logout button in such a way that on clicking the logout button it should navigate to rootviewcontroller. please go through my storyboard interface to get a clear understanding. Any help is much appreciated
[image: storyboard]

Comment: i think you are using modal segue in table view?... so it is not going back to home view....

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma hmmm I am presenting it as a popover.. now how to go back to root view controller after clicking logout button... where do i need to implement that functionality.?

Comment: you should make the login view apart from your other view, and create a check in `AppDelegate`, if the user is logout, present the login view, the same in that view with logout button, if the user press,  dismiss your view and present the login view

Comment: `presentViewController` is using `modalPresentationStyle`. So you cannot use `unwind` if you're using it now.

Comment: you should put your navigation controller before your root View controller... so after this you can call this method to remove all modal views from your view like this                                                           [[[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] parentViewController] parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: @zcui93 i am using modalPresentationStyle to present logout button as a popover so how can i program it accordingly so that on clicking logout button user should be navigated to rootViewController

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is deprecated now... :-(

Comment: sorry use dismissViewControllerAnimated instead... i apologizes

Comment: root your app in a navigation controller, then when you want to log out, whereever you may be, just call this:  [[(FRAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate customRootViewController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:true]; then you will be logged out back at the home screen assuming you have you app set up this way with a property of "customRootViewController" as a property of your appdelegate. set the @property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController * customRootViewController;

Comment: @Larcerax i am presently using this functionality on click event `                          -(IBAction)LogoutButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"home screen logout button is clicked");
    MainViewController *mvc = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:mvc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }`                                                                                                                 please let me know where am i going wrong and moreover this function has been implemented in UITableViewController which is LogouttableViewController in this case

Comment: It's very complicated to explain this simply, but the idea is that since everything in your app is part of appdelegate hierarchy, then the root contorller of your entire app, if accessed, will discard everything on top of it's stack. The way I do this is the following: as the root of the app delegate is a splach screen controller, the second controller on the stack is the tabbarcontroller. so when you pop to the root of the app, the sign up/log in screen is always presented since it the root of the whole app.

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma dismissViewControllerAnimated isn't working either :-(

Comment: It doesn't matter where you button is placed, it can be placed whereever you want it to be placed and the pop to the root of the entire app is possible. I have a view heirarchy that is 5 navigation controllers deep with two presented view controllers over another three view controllers all embedded in navigation conrollers of their own, and pressing the logout button, removes the app off the stack in full and drops back to the root view which is the log in screen.

Comment: @Larcerax in my case there are two different login screens one for A and another one for B so in that scenario does your solution still work..? or do i need to handle it differently in this scenario..?

Comment: Nah, you can do this sort of, just have a splashscreen, and then have two buttons on this screen. the splashscreen can be the rootviewcontroller of the app's navigation controller. then the splash screen can show "log in as user b" or "log in as user a" .. or just have the same screen for both login methods but change the target event of the button listenser to a different method based on your needs.

Comment: also, you can set up whatever hierarchy you want, you don't need to pop all the way down to the rootview of the application. you can pop go any parent navigation controller of a viewcontrolelr your are in. So, if you want a robust hiearchy at the start of your app and when someone logs out it sends them to a secondary hiearchy that is rooted in the apps root navigation cotorller then you can do all sorts of stuff with this. You can root a tableviewcontroler, another tabbar controller, or whatever you want.

Comment: @Larcerax I am managing the login screens based on the button clicking events here is a glimpse of my code `- (IBAction)LoginButtonTouch:(id)sender {
    if(_CheckButton.selected){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"VendorLogin" sender:self];
//        NSLog(@"button selected");
    }
    else {
              [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CustomerLogin" sender:self];
    }
}`

Comment: that's simple then, just have a screen with a button on that, and then make this scren the rootivewcontroller of the UInavigationcontroller at the root of your app.

Comment: that "mainviewcontroller" at the beginning of your storyboard, make it a viewcontroller rooted in a navigation controller, you can't pop to a viewcontroller unless it has a navigation controller

Comment: @Larcerax here is my final storyboard hierarchy please go through it and let me know how best should my approach be.. [http://s18.postimg.org/lcoragu2x/final_Story_Board_Hierarchy.png]

Comment: So, your entry point in the the app, the "->" .. should point to the navigation controller, not the first viewcontroller you have there. You don't need to use a UIViewController as the entry point, just use the UINavigationController with rootviewController as the entry point, then you have the set up i;m talking about. I don't use storyboards, but I know what they do, it would be easier to show you in code, but probably not in your case because you are using storyboards., but do as I explained above, if this makes sense and you have your setup

Comment: Just make sure you have the navigationcontroller IBOutlet declared in your AppDelegate.h file

Comment: @Larcerax That was quite helpful but in my case i do need the starting view controller as it further connects to another view here is my final hierarchy sorry i couldn't be much expressive earlier [http://s23.postimg.org/3twby8k7v/final_Story_Board.png]

Comment: @Larcerax the starting view is kind of home screen and it further navigates to login screen and another screen

Comment: @ashwin yep, and it can still be that way, you just need to root that view in a navigationController. a navigationcontroller manages a stack of viewcontrollers. so you can still have your custom view there, just place it in a navigationcontroler. the funcationality and the view won't change

Comment: @Larcerax now the main question arises even though i integrate the root view into a navigation controller how can i say my button to come out to login screen on clicking that button do i need to use any sort of identifiers of login screen..? if yes could you please let me know how can i use that identifier

Comment: So, its like this, MainAppNavControl ->ViewController(log in screen, lets say) -> more viewControllers etc. ... so on the log in screen, just have your login buttons that are attached to button handlers that are then attached to more viewonctollers. I don't know what you are asking exactly hwere, but this is how it works. clafiy if you can

Comment: @Larcerax hmm its kind of my question is how should i make a handshake with the logout button and say when it is being clicked please come to the login screen.. do i need to use any kind of storyboard identifiers or anything else

Comment: yes, I see, so, doing this in code, I'd do it this way. in the AppDelegate.h, I declare the @propety UINavigationController *appRootController. This declaration exposes this navigationcontroller to the app. Using IBOutets, just attach this property to the navigationcontroller in your view heirarchy at the entry point in your storyboards. then you sbould be able to call to this navigagtion controller like so: [[(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate appRootController]  .. this will POP to the rootveiwcontroller. so this call is attached to your logout button

Comment: you don't need to do anything more than what I explained above. If you set the property correctly in your AppDelegate, then you expose your entire app to the "appRootController" and can therefore call to this navigationcontroller whenever you want by calling the AppDelegate since it's a delegate of UIApplication delegate

Comment: @Larcerax K what u have explained me so far is indicating this way please correct me if i am wrong... i need to create navigation controller to my rootViewController(main screen) which makes me navigate to rootViewController(main screen) on clicking logout button but in my case i am asking the other one if i click on the logout button i should be navigated to LoginScreen but not the MainScreen... if i have understood U in the wrong way i am sorry but if we can use the terms LOGINSCREEN and MAINSCREEN it will be helpful to our conversation...

Comment: Yep, so the loginscreen is the rootviewcontroller of the the mainscreen navigationcontroller. Remember, UINavigationControllers display viewcontrollers, that's their purpose. so the loginscreen will show since it's sitting in the UINavigationController. UInavigationcontrtollers server no other purpose than to manage viewcontrollers. but you can't navigate in a viewcontroller unless this viewcontroller is first inside a navigationcontroller

Comment: You can do this also, just root the main screen, and then add an out let to the logion screen in the login screen's .h file. Then, you must traverse through the viewcontroller's navigationcontroller heirarchy and find that login screen's navigationcontroller, when you find it, pop to it.

Comment: it could be as deep as this: self.navigationController.navigationController.navigationController popToRootViewController .. etc.

Comment: but this is how you would easily traverse through the heiarchy, just drop back to the first navigationcontroller that you want to pop to and then pop to it, but this one may not be so straight forward, you must call to the this naivgationcontroller as customview controller or a parentviewcontorller which makes this complicated, but unless i had your code, I won't be able to tell. I have to test this stuff when I use it myself to make sure I'm  transporting to the correctly navigationcontroller.

Comment: @Larcerax I can traverse back from login screen to main screen as i have implemented dismissViewController method by adding a cancel BarButtonItem to the top of LOGINSCREEN so my main concern is traversing back to the LOGINSCREEN when clicking the Logout button and one more thing is i have added this login screen to a navigation controller already as been showed earlier in the final hierarchy png [http://s23.postimg.org/3twby8k7v/final_Story_Board.png] so now thinking only about traversing to login screen how to proceed

Comment: @Larcerax if you would like to have a glimpse of my code i can provide it but dunno how to drop it to u.... :-( just let me know how could i provide u the code

Comment: just screen shot the app delegate .h and .m files adn then load it to imgur.com, I'll look at it quickly when I have free minute later, that's fine. I don't need to see the entire code base,

Comment: BUT hide your app keys and stuff if you have them there in the delegate for any services, you dont' want that stuff on the internet

Comment: @Larcerax as suggested by you i am attaching the screenshots and somehow i think it wouldn't be much helpful i haven't implemented any navigation controller property in appdelegate.h still [http://s24.postimg.org/phn2r06k5/appdelegate_h.png] and the rest of the code in appdelegate.m is core data basic code in the screen shot if u still like me to upload the entire code i will [http://s2.postimg.org/m04tjfr09/appdelegate_m.png] and let me know if u need anything for further clarification

Comment: perfect, i'll look at them, from jsut a brief look over, it might be eaiser if I load a quick gist for you of what I mean on some of this. keep looking over this answer throghout the next 10 hours or so

Comment: @Larcerax did u find anything...?